# React Native: Device Screen Time

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, mobile-application

I need to access device screen time, not just of my app but also of other apps, from my React Native app. However I could not find anything about it. I know there are some apps for some parental control sort of things, so there should be a way to do it but I do not know how. Please, I need help.